# Which button was clicked to open form

Tags: vb.net, sender

I have a form that loads from a click of any of three buttons (Add, Modify or Delete). When the form loads there is a 'Confirm' button which will perform a task depending on which button was originally used to show the form.

Is there an easy way to determine which button was originally clicked so that the right code can be executed?

Thanks

Comment: It's the job of the buttons to tell the form. Add a property with an enum indicating the origin of the form and set that property after the form is created in each button.

Comment: Just pass a value to the confirm form via the constructor what "mode" it should be in.

Comment: You have to pass the action as argument to the constructor of the form or to `ShowDialog`. Then you can use that property. Therefore you could create an `Enum` with these three values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well suppose to define at the global level an enum like this

```
Public Enum CommandAction
    Create
    Modify 
    Delete
End Enum
```

Now in the code used to launch your second form to execute the Add command, you could write code like this (of course you repeat the same but varying the CommandAction in the other buttons).

```
Dim myFormInstance = new MyForm(CommandAction.Create)
myFormInstance.ShowDialog()
```

Finally, add a specfic constructor for your second form (`MyForm` in this example). 
A constructor that receives and saves for future usage a CommandAction

```
Public Class MyForm
    Dim cmd as CommandAction

    Public Sub New(command as CommandAction )
         InitializeComponent()
         cmd = command
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
         InitializeComponent()
         cmd = CommandAction.Create ' Set a default'
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now in the code where you need to decide which kind of action to execute, just look at the value of the global `cmd` variable and execute the appropriate block of code

**NOTE**  Adding a specific constructor to a form class requires the explicit presence of the standard empty constructor.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'm getting an initial error on the first bit of code `Dim myFormInstance = new MyForm(CommandAction.Create)
myFormInstance.ShowDialog()` Its showing "Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()' - I'm putting this in the Click Event right??

Comment: Did you add to your second form (the so called class MyForm, the one that has the Confirm button) the two constructor (Public Sub New) above?

Comment: Sorry, typed manually. It is `InitializeComponent` (singular). This Sub exists in every form class. It is in the Form.Designer.vb file.

Answer (score -1):

first put a hidden field with some name like "clicked". Make a javascript function with one parameter to put values in to the hidden field. Call the function on click of every button but set some specific value for each button. In this way you will be able to run right code for each button on submit. If not understand then do tell me, i'll help you in the code.